# Issues installing PhantomJS for windows: command not recognized

Tags: windows, path, phantomjs

following the docs here: http://attester.ariatemplates.com/usage/phantom.html, I am trying to install phantomjs on my windows machine.

I tried adding multiple lines to my Path system variable, and yet, I get the same error in the command prompt when I type in `phantomjs --version`.

" 'phantomjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I added the phantomjs.exe to `C:\phantomjs\bin\`, and added `C:\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs` to the path, and any variation that I could think of, such as:

```
C:\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs.exe\; C:\phantomjs\bin; C:\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs\;
```

How am I not installing this right?

Comment: add only C:\phantomjs\bin\ to your path. Restart your comman prompt and check.

Comment: @Chandan Your comment should be the answer )

Comment: @Vaviloff added as an answer... thanks

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to put all the directories to the environment PATH variable.

Add only following to your path and restart your command prompt.

`C:\phantomjs\bin\`

Comment: I tried running the command phantomjs --version from any directory in the command prompt. When I navigated to the folder, it worked. I'm a fool.

Answer (score -3):

Add **phantomjs.exe** to **C:\Windows\System32** folder.

Comment: That would work but adding files to the system folders seems like a bad idea, its better to add it to its own folder and add that folder to the Path environment variable.